# Calling function after calling super constructor in bloc constructor

Tags: flutter, bloc

I was watching a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THCkkQ-V1-8&t=7164s) about bloc and stream subscription and I noticed this piece of code. Right after the super constructor, he called a function.

```
class InternetCubit extends Cubit<InternetState> {
  final Connectivity connectivity;
  late StreamSubscription connectivityStreamSubscription;

  InternetCubit({required this.connectivity}) : super(InternetLoading()) {
    connectivityStreamSubscription = connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult connectivityResult) {
      if(connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi){
        emitInternetConnected(ConnectionType.Wifi);
      }
      else if(connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile){
        emitInternetConnected(ConnectionType.Mobile);
      }else if(connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none){
        emitDisconnected();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Can anyone explains to me what this function after the super constructor is called? And what does it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone explains to me what this function after the super
> constructor is called?

This is not a function, it's just a constructor's body: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors

> And what does it do?

In this case, during the `InternetCubit` initialization, cubit subscribes to
`connectivity.onConnectivityChanged` stream events. Then, on each `connectivityResult` event, the corresponding cubit state change is triggered. This is useful when your cubit state should change on custom cubit events (e.g. when you call a cubit method from UI) as well as other event sources e.g. internet connectivity status provided by the `connectivity` package.